# Cities names list against a selected country in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, location, ios11, xcode9, country

I am working on an iOS App in which i want to get the temperature of different cities in different countries. I am able to get the country list which is a local  csv file, but i would like to get the cities list against the country which i selected. Is there any way to do so ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You do not have to have ".csv" file for countries. It can be done like in the following `Github` project: https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker/blob/master/CountryPicker/CountryPicker.m

Comment: I am not sure though how to get cities for a given country: currently struggling with it myself.